# Nagios - Setting a host as down when passive checks freshness is expired?

Tags: nagios

The environment has only passive check enables. Active checks are not possible.

The objective of the configuration is that Nagios report a host as "Down" when the host has not reported information (not reported passive checks) for a longer time than the freshness is configured.

I have created a very simple lab environment replicating the same firewall rules as in the original environment and the same setup. The lab consists of just 1 NagioXI Server and 1 Linux client.

For testing purposes, I have configured the freshness in the services checks and in the host configuration. In both cases, when the freshness threshold is exceeded the same check command is executed which is a check_dummy ARG1= 2 (Critical) and Arg2= "Server down" or something like down.

In the Services checks the Alert work perfectly fine. After the freshness threshold is exceeded, the Critical status is displayed.
In the host configurations, however, the host is always reported as Up and no message is displayed.

Config on the Services

[image]

Config on the Host

[image]

Check Command

[image]

And all the services are Down with Critical status as I would expect but this is not what I want to achieve. I want to achieve a Host down status however the host is always Up.

[image]

Host Status

[image]

How can I set the host as status down?

Comment: Did you try setting `max_check_attempts` to 1?

Comment: I tried after your suggestion, still the same

Comment: Did you perform at least one passive check to get it out of initial state? (I don't have a clear answer as your settings look the same as mine, which is working, otherwise)

Comment: Yes, the client has reported many times to the server. When the client start reporting, all services become up immediately, and when stops reporting, services become red. However Host is always up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting, I finally manage to find the problem.
The problem was that the Check Host Freshness was disabled in *nagios.cfg* file

After changing:

```
check_host_freshness=0
```

with

```
check_host_freshness=1
```

Immediately start working :)

Obs: as Tater mention in the comments, Max Attempts need to be set to 1 for it to work as expected in my case.